# EditText Alternatives in a Widget? There has to be a way

Tags: android, android-widget, textview, android-edittext, htcsense

Has anyone ever successfully implemented an EditText in a widget? I realize Android does not support this, however, "Friend Stream" on HTC devices does it... Is this due to an HTC feature? Could I implement this on HTC? Anyone have any crazy creative ideas for implementing a textbox which actually allows typing on a homescreen widget?

*ANY* possible leads on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most of this can be google-ed, expept for the style of TextViews (you can not use EditText in widget..)

But.. go with the style property.. :)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/etBlahblah"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Using this and then adding a clickable ="true" then call an activity that has edit field.

Answer (score 15):

A way to do this is to make a tap on your widget start a new activity (standard) and to make this activity fully transparent. There are ways to retrieve your widget's position, so that you can position a TextView in your activity on top of your widget. Make a tap outside of your TextView close the activity. I think this is what the Google search widget does, you may want to look at this code.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks. This is interesting. The google widget doesn't seem to try that hard... just moves it to the top of the screen in the new activity it launches.

Comment: Thanks Gilles that seems like an interesting logic. I can put a button inplace of the text box but I cant make it look like a search box. How could I possible do that?

Comment: Use Images or check @Stefan's answer