# Android searchbar like google app

Tags: android, searchbar

I want to develop search bar like bellow image just like showing in Google search bar. How to achieve this. Please some can provide sample code or related links to achieve it.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter while trying it? Somebody with you SO reputation should know how to ask better questions than this and avoid things that are off-topic for SO (requests for off-site resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the actual question here is not how to create a widget (if it is, check the official Android documentation on widgets), but how you can enable a widget to receive text input, which, as far as i am aware, is not possible using [standard widget elements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

You will probably have to try the way discussed [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435808/edittext-alternatives-in-a-widget-there-has-to-be-a-way) - creating a transparent activity when your widget is tapped.